# How to install plotnine Python package of Void Linux

Tags: package-management, python, void-linux

I want to install Python package [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in Void Linux. I have been able to install many Python packages (e.g. numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas etc) from Void repositories. However, `plotnine` is not there in the repositories.

Pip is also not working.

How can I install `plotnine` Python package in Void Linux? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "pip is also not working" mean exactly?

Comment: `pip search plotnine`  and `pip search ggplot` are giving error.

Comment: What isn't working is command-line `pip search`, see https://status.python.org/incidents/grk0k7sz6zkp. Pip is working just fine. Use the web form on https://pypi.org/ to search, and you'll find https://pypi.org/project/plotnine/. Plotnine seems current, but beware: ggplot packages seem obsolete.

Comment: Yes, it works. Is it better to install Python packages through pip or through Void repositories?

Comment: I can't speak for Void because this is the first time I'm hearing about it. From the python side of things it's usually a good idea to use a virtualenv and pip install everything into it. But your mileage may vary.